# Can this 2-liner jquery be shortened to 1 line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these divs, each have the same class `.onediv` and distinct ids `div1, div2, div3`

```
<div class="alldivs">
   <div class="onediv" id="div1">
   </div>
   <div class="onediv" id="div2">
   </div>
   <div class="onediv" id="div3">
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to use jquery to change their css `display` property so that all of them are `display none` except `id=div2` which is `display block`. Right now I'm doing it this way with 2 lines. Is there a quicker way to do the same thing with one line only?

```
$('.onediv').css('display', 'none');    
$('#div2').css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: do you want to do it through css...or want it through jquery

Comment: There is no value in condensing this into one line. Clarity over cleverness

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're hiding/showing amongst siblings then the most generic (and still performant) solution is to use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), like this:

```
$("#div2").show().siblings().hide();
```

Note that [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) are shortcuts for setting the `display` CSS property like you want here (between `none` and what it was before, `block` in the default `<div>` case).

Comment: since #div2 is already in a "show" state, there's no point in using .show().  Also, using something generic like .siblings() can be a dangerous thing, as it is not specifically selecting the .onediv class.  If he were to add other things in there that .alldivs class shouldn't be hidden, this code would break that

Comment: @Crayon - `#div2` is *not* in a show state, that's what the code is showing, I think you should re-read the question carefully.  The question says that's what the *result* should be, not what the situation currently is.  If you think about where this would be used, it's pretty obvious what the OP is after, showing one section at a time.

Comment: @Crayon - Also just a note, you can do `.siblings(".onediv")` if you need a check in there, but the approach is the same.  Note the name of the class `.onediv`, as in show one at a time :)

Comment: @Nick: No, the divs are initially in a show state.  Then the first jQuery statement hides all of them.  But he doesn't want to hide all of them. He wants to hide all of them *except* #div2, so he makes a 2nd jQuery statement to show it again to reverse what the first query did.

Comment: @Crayon - Due respect, you're making some very bas assumptions not in evidence here...I think once the OP clarifies you'll see what they actually want to do is show any of the divs, one at a time, like sections on a home page.  Any could be shown before this code is run, and you'll need to hide the others and show the desired one to get where you want to go.  This is a **very** common use case.

Comment: @Nick: Ah okay, I see what you're saying now.  My apologies. If you edit your answer I can give you down-vote back :(

Answer (score 2):

`$('.onediv:not(#div2)').css('display', 'none');`

Comment: This would only hide those unwanted...it wouldn't show `#div2`

Comment: umm, yes it would, this says to hide everything *except* #div2

Comment: also, why don't you try it out yourself before down-voting. THANKS.

Comment: 1) I didn't downvote you, someone else who sees this isn't what the OP is asking for did.  And 2) this doesn't answer the question, **it doesn't do what the original code did**.  Any of the *other* divs could be shown before this code runs, your code certainly doesn't solve that, they'll just all be hidden or it'll have no effect.  The code is supposed to have *that result* described in the question, you're interpreting it as that's how the `display` properties *start*...then why would there be any code at all?  This is a misinterpretation of the question.

Comment: @Nick: No Nick, you're missing the point.  I suggest *you* reread the question.  "I want to use jquery to change their css display property so that all of them are display none except id=div2".  The only reason he has two jquery statements is the 2nd one is to make up for the 1st one doing what he does *not* want it to do: make #div2 hidden

Answer (score 2):

it is possible using `filter` function, but not recommended for performance reason:

```
$('.onediv').hide().filter('#div2').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#div2').siblings().css('display', 'none');

Answer (score 0):

Here is a creative one (but not necessarily useful):

```
$(".alldivs > div:even").hide();
```

Here is another one:

```
$(".onediv:not(:eq(1))").hide();
```

*This code expects that by default your divs are not hidden (ie. no display:none in your css)*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.onediv').not('.onediv:last-child').css('display', 'none');
```

Please don't downrank! this works. check here: http://jsfiddle.net/ASBcg/

EDIT:
If you want explicitly show that div this would be better:

```
$('.onediv').css('display', 'block').not('.onediv:last-child').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: You're showing #div3 with this, not #div2...and overall this is just a bad approach, as you're in no way relating to the element the OP wants to show.

Comment: I think this question is wrong from the beginning, what is the reason to write a code in just one line? Also we can address that div with n-th child that is supported in jQuery

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question, the OP wants to show a `<div>` *with the given id*, not by position or anything else...see my answer on how to do this very simply :)